# Mac OS - m1: Can't install ruby 2.7.5 because of an error from configure

Tags: ruby, react-native, macos, rvm, apple-m1

I need to install ruby 2.7.5 for my react native app but I can't install 2.7.5 through rvm. I tried many things to install any ruby version, I ended up to get this configure error.

```
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/1672107647_ruby-2.1.1/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Here is the configure log

```
configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
checking for ruby... /usr/bin/ruby
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking target system type... arm-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/myname/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.1':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

I tried...

1. remove rvm and reinstall

- `rvm install 2.7.5`
- `rvm install ruby-2.7.5`

2. use rbenv
3. install openssl

- `brew install openssl`
- `rvm install 2.6.7 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl`

4. remove rvm by using rvm implode

all those throw same error message. After trying 4., all ruby versions are removed but still can't install any ruby version.

Please help!!!

Edit
I tried
`CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.7.5`

and got this error

```
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5  --with-opt-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/libyaml:/opt/homebrew/opt/libksba:/opt/homebrew/opt/readline:/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1 --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/1672116807_ruby-2.7.5/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

EDIT-----

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

export RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" 
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
rvm install 2.7.5
```

this returns same error
but I got this configure log

```
checking for ruby... /usr/bin/ruby
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking target system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/myname/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.5':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs. // <---- new!
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

------ EDIT --------
after 2days, I try to install 2.7.6 and got this message again.

```
checking for ruby... /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/bin/ruby
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking target system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/Users/myname/.rvm/src/ruby-2.7.6':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add Command Line Tools:

```
Ensure the command line tools are correctly installed. We might need to reinstall Xcode after OS upgrades.
```

Here are the exact steps to follow assuming we have openssl installed

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"

export RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC
export optflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)" 
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"
rvm install 2.7.5
```

Comment: thank you again for answering the question! I have a short simple basic question for you. So.. I should enter those lines into the terminal one line by one line?

Comment: Yes one by one.

Comment: with entering one line by one line, I still got the same exact error (crying..)

Comment: actually, I got little different configure log. let me add this into the question.

Comment: Command line tools are missing on your end. run this open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg Change the version as per your OS.

Comment: by entering this line in the terminal?

Comment: First check the version of your OS and based on that you will have to install command line tools which will compile C based libraries. What is your OS version?

Comment: it is Vetura 13.1

Comment: Lets discuss over chat. I think there are some files missing i your installation. You will have to redo your xcode installation. You need to reinstall your xcode installation. https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/2.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250669/discussion-between-payal-and-cindy).

Comment: @Cindy : You can enter them manually, but this is error prone and tedious to repeat. Instead I would paste the whole code posted by _Payal_ into a script, and then source the script. This makes it also easier to discuss problems which still occur afterwards.

Comment: @Payal Thank you for helping me to figure out to install ruby2.7.5. Today I try to install 2.7.6 and it throws exactly same error that I had on 26. I went through all steps(rebooting) but I was not able to install 2.7.6. I remember you mentioned that openssl is not supporting 2.7.x. Do you think that is 2.6.7?

Comment: @user1934428 thank you for the advice. You mentioned that the err will be repeated. Does it mean I will get the same error whenever I install new ruby version?

Comment: I didn't say anything in ths respect. I just said in reply to your question "enter those lines into the terminal one line by one line?", that for fixing or trying something, it is less error-prone to first put all commands into a script and then source the script. This makes you repeat the process easily, and helps sharing the code on stackoverflow. When you later install a different ruby again, this script could help in doing the same then for the new version.

Comment: @Cindy What is the error you getting? Not the C compiler one? Is it openssl error?

Comment: @Payal I got `configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.` err message. I updated error log.

Comment: @Cindy https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250669/discussion-between-payal-and-cindy Please come to chat section.

Comment: @Payal I missed the chat meeting. Please let me know anytime if you can join the chat room again.

Comment: Hi @Cindy I joined.

Comment: @Payal I am in the chat room now!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have xcode developer tools installed? Run this "xcode-select --install"

```
xcode-select --install
```

Once you have developer tools installed you may need to refer to this comment:-

https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1947#discussioncomment-2317356

Comment: thank you for the comment! I think installed xcode successfully already. In case, I tried the above comment and I got this `xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates` Also, I already tried the link that you added at the bottom but I haven't got any luck to fix this issue. I wonder..if need to set up something in Xcode?

Comment: Ok, Are you following this documentation https://rvm.io/rvm/install to install rvm? Lets do it step by step. What does "rvm list" print out on your end?

Comment: I just removed rvm and reinstall with this instruction(https://nrogap.medium.com/install-rvm-in-macos-step-by-step-d3b3c236953b) Now, my `rvm list` is displaying `# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.`

Comment: CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.7.5

Comment: Run above command to install 2.7.5 version

Comment: I have tried this and I still get same error. I added the result of `CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rvm install 2.7.5` @payal I have same error and confiure log

Comment: I see the error now, give me few minutes to debug. Thank you.

Comment: Cindy, please follow the step in the below answer. Make sure you have installed openssl 1.1 using home brew and running which openssl will display the path of openssl which is referenced in the below commands. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: where is below answer? you meant this? https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/1947#discussioncomment-2317356 If so, I already tried and got the same error message :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74925998/5800615 This is the answer. I was gettign same error as you and then i was able to install using these instructions. Assuming /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1 is the path to openssl. You can get your path using which openssl.